# Pattern for Java generics for "internal" type

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class. Its public interface (excluding the constructor) is not generic, but its internal logic is. A simplified example of this is:

```
class Summarizer<T> {
  private final ComplicatedProducer<T> producer;
  private final Processor<T> processor;

  StreamSummarizer(ComplicatedProducer<T> producer, Processor<T> processor) {
     ...
  }

  public int summarizeAll() {
    int sum = 0
    // some business logic goes here
    for (...) {
      sum += processor.process(producer.next());
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public int summarizeSomePortion(Parameters p) {
    // some other business logic goes here
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that (after construction), the user of `Summarizer` has no interest in `T`'s type. In my case, the type isn't known at compile time (we use reflection to construct `ComplicatedProducer` and `Processor`), and I'd rather not have to have a factory function that returns `Summarizer<?>`. Is there any clean way to make `Summarizer` non-generic without resorting to the use of raw types?

Comment: Why is `ComplicatedProducer` generic? Why do you not use `ComplicatedProducer<? extends Object>`? Same goes for `Processor`.

Comment: Because `ComplicatedProducer<T>::next()` returns `T` and `Processor<T>::process` takes a `T` as a parameter. The actual methods are more complicated than that and it's useful for their interactions to be type-checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always have a single-level wrapper:

```
class SummarizerImpl<T> {
    private final ComplicatedProducer<T> producer;
    private final Processor<T> processor;

    SummarizerImpl(ComplicatedProducer<T> producer, Processor<T> processor) {
      ...
    }
}

class Summarizer {
   private final SummarizerImpl<?> impl;
   private Summarizer(SummarizerImpl<?> impl) { ... }
   public static <T> Summarizer create(
       ComplicatedProducer<T> producer, Processor<T> processor) {
     return new Summarizer(new SummarizerImpl<T>(producer, processor));
   }
}
```

Comment: Is what happened here we that we abstracted the work Summarizer would to do SummarizerImpl ? Is create a factory method for Summarizer? I am new to Java and am just going through trying to figure out where the original methods in the question went.

Comment: You need them in both; the `Summarizer` ones will just call into the `SummarizerImpl` ones.

Comment: May I ask for an concrete example, if there is a readily available one, of a similar structure? I would like to try running the code and modifying it myself to get a better sense of what's going on but I would need something concrete. Of course, I will attempt something with the code already here but I think I would need some guidance still.